Can't move vertices with G
I'm trying to make a cherry kind of shaped glass.
I am trying to achieve this with smooth and G.

It worked out so I wanted to try it on a sphere with a radius I actually need but when I add a sphere and change the radius I can only move it downwards and upwards with z axis.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens or what I am doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more information.
English isn't my native language.


Not really sure exactly what you are trying to do. You should be able to move the vertex of the second sphere that you've added in exactly the same way as you did with the first one. It might be an idea to share your Blend file so that we can see what's going on.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Hello thank you, I have added the file. I'm trying to move the above part of the sphere with G, I can do this if I just add a sphere without changing the radius, when I add a new sphere with a changed radius I can only move the whole sphere with G, hope this was a bit more clear

You have proportional editing turned on in the first picture. The z axis difference there is 37 cm, so it looks to be the default scale of the sphere. In the second picture, the sphere is much smaller, as you can tell from the coordinates of the top vertex in the top right corner of the viewport. If you shrink it so much, the entire sphere is in the effective radius of the proportional editing, so the whole thing is moving with the top vertex. To change the radius of the proportional editing, use your mouse wheel.

TRUE HERO!!! Thank you so much :)

@Heavenly you're welcome :)
